# ASP.NET MVC attribute routing not hitting correct controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a couple of controllers like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("side-navigation")]
public class SideNavigationController : BaseController
{
    [Route("{pathname}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string pathname)
    {
        SideNavigationPopoutModel model = _sideNavFactory.Value.CreatePopout(pathname);

        if (model != null)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}

public class CatchAllController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index(string pathname)
    {
        CatchAllModel model = _catchAllModelFactory.Value.Create(pathname);

        if (model != null)
        {
            // TODO: Do we need this - what does it do?
            // TempData.Restore(this);

            return View(model);
        }

        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}
```

But I cannot seem to get to my index action in the side navigation controller - if I browse to `localhost/side-navigation/test` it's hitting the catch all controller with `side-navigation/test` as it's pathname instead of the side navigation one with `test` as the pathname.

Can anyone see anything I am doing wrong here or how to make the side navigation controller work?

This is the route config:

```
// MVC attribute routing
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

// Default catch all route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{*pathname}",
    new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index" });
```

Weirdly, if I change the route of the side navigation index to `test/{pathname}` and browse to `side-navigation/test/test` it will work and the controller will be hit but I don't want to add anything before the pathname

Comment: Try with this:  `routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", 
                "{controller}/{id}", 
                new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index", id = "" });`

Comment: Sorry, wouldn't this just allow for an id parameter on the url and default it to an empty string?  Not sure how that would solve the routing problem, anyway gave it a try and it just breaks the catchall routing

Comment: Sorry its a mistake.. you can try with this: `routes.MapRoute( "Default", "{controller}/{id}", new { controller = "CatchAll", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have fixed this by adding an asterisk before the pathname:

```
[RoutePrefix("side-navigation")]
public class SideNavigationController : BaseController
{
    [Route("{*pathname}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string pathname)
    {
    }
}
```

If anyone can explain why this works and without an asterisk doesn't, it would be greatly appreciated, as I also have a product controller set up in exactly the same way that doesn't need the asterisk

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using [Area] also put attribute [Route("[action]")] above method.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work and I don't want to add an area to the url structure (which is why I'm not using area attributes)

Answer (score -3):

[RoutePrefix("side-navigation")]
public class SideNavigationController : BaseController
{
    [Route("{*pathname}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string pathname)
    {
    }
}

Comment: can you explain why this should be a solution?

Comment: You just seem to have copied the code from my answer but not formatted or explained why it should work so not sure what this is adding really